# How to find a job in New Zealand or Australia without work visa?

Tags: working-visas, australia, employment, new-zealand

Employers will offer Job only if I have Work Visa, I can get Work visa only if I have valid offer letter. I am in this deadlock situation.

I am from India having 4 years of experience in IT industry. I am looking for a Job in New Zealand / Australia. When I apply for any job the first condition they impose is "Citizenship / Work Visa/ PR". I contacted some consultancies also, they also tell  me the same. Employers will offer job only if I have work Visa, I can get work visa only if I have valid offer letter.

Is there a way to get through this?

Comment: For hard-to-fill jobs, many employers will be willing to go through all the extra work of getting you a visa. Have you made sure you're applying for roles that can't easily be filled by locals?

Comment: There is no job-seeker VISA concept for AUS/NZ unlike Germany. Why would you prefer Aus&NZ over european and american nations in such situation?

Comment: A start point could be to check out https://stackoverflow.com/jobs and search for jobs in Australia/New Zealand that offer to sponsor overseas candidates. From past experience I know that [Readify](https://readify.net/) are one that do this (or did, about a year ago).

Answer (score 4):

The best solution for Australia is to apply for [General Skilled Migration](https://www.immi.gov.au/skilled/general-skilled-migration/), which gives you (provisional) permanent residence.

However, it's a long and arduous path, especially after the recent clampdown on "abuse" of the system: you can't even apply directly anymore, you need to submit an "expression of interest" and wait to get invited to apply.  Even when granted, there are (initially) quite a few strings attached about where you can work and what kind of jobs you can work in.

Answer (score 3):

New Zealand has a special sort of Skilled Migrant Worker programme, where you can apply for a visa, and if it's approved, you can come live in NZ and then start looking for work:

http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/skilledmigrant/default.htm

Wouldn't be surprised if Australia had the same thing.

Comment: This process takes lot of time esp from India

Comment: @Gopal It would take 6 months(max). Process is very reliable. I have applied by end of april for NZ PR. As per the current immigration process across countries, NZ is the only hope. Don't miss that as neuron says. Canada process has become more difficult than normal after Jan 2015.

Comment: @neuron Australia also has such process, but language score(IELTS) is bit demanding.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask an employer to give you a job offer that's conditional on a visa, with a sensible and specific expiry date. That should be adequate for applying for a visa.

Ensure the employer knows how far into the future the expiry date needs to be so that there's time for the visa to be processed, or the offer may lapse before you get your visa. Obviously, you'll need to find out how long it typically takes to get a visa, and you'll need your application ready to go. If you tell an employer your visa application is ready to submit, they would hopefully be impressed with your motivation, and be more likely to make the effort to make you an offer.

Comment: Most of the Jobs applications are advertized by Consultancies and they do demand Work visa for further processing.